# protobuf-net does not deserialize DateTime.Kind correctly

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protobuf-net, globalization

using `protobuf-net.dll` Version 1.0.0.280

When I deserialize a `DateTime` (wrapped in an object), the date/time is ok but the `DateTime.Kind` property is 'Unspecified'

Consider this test case to serialize/deserialize a DateTime.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDateTimeSerialization()
{
    var obj = new DateTimeWrapper {Date = DateTime.UtcNow};
    obj.Date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(obj.Date, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var serialized = obj.SerializeProto();
    var deserialized = serialized.DeserializeProto<DateTimeWrapper>();
    Assert.AreEqual(DateTimeKind.Utc, deserialized.Date.Kind);
}

public static byte[] SerializeProto<T>(this T item) where T : class
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, item);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public static T DeserializeProto<T>(this byte[] raw) where T : class, new()
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(raw))
    {
        return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(ms);
    }
}
```

The Assert fails, the Kind == `Unspecified`

## Addendum

As a result of `protobuf-net` not serializing this property (see below) one solution is to assume `DateTimeKind` is equal to Utc when displaying dates on the client side (only where you **know** it should be UTC of course):

```
public static DateTime ToDisplayTime(this DateTime utcDateTime, TimeZoneInfo timezone)
{
    if (utcDateTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc)//may be Unspecified due to serialization
        utcDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(utcDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcDateTime, timezone);
    return result;
}
```

This saves you having to assign to each `DateTime` property on the receiving side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

protobuf.net has to maintain compatibility with the protobuf binary format, which is designed for the Java date/time datatypes.  No `Kind` field in Java -> No `Kind` support in the protobuf binary format -> `Kind` not transferred across the network.  Or something along those lines.

As it turns out, protobuf.net encodes the `Ticks` field (only), you'll find the code in [`BclHelpers.cs`](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net/BclHelpers.cs#135).

But feel free to add another field in your protobuf message definition for this value.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of other 'lossful' serialization as a result of the protobuf binary format?

Comment: I recently ran into this issue. If the `DateTimeKind` is not `Unspecified`, it should be safe to call `ToUniversalTime()` when using the deserialized `DateTime`. This will set the `DateTimeKind` to `Utc`, and it will be correct because `Ticks` doesn't change based on the `DateTimeKind`.

NOTE: This will *not* necessarily be safe if `DateTimeKind` is `Unspecified` *before* serializing.

Answer (score 5):

As an extension to Ben's answer... strictly speaking, protobuf *has* no definition of time, so there is nothing to retain compatibility with. I'm tempted to add support for this in v2, but sadly it would add 2 bytes per value. I have yet to think about whether this is acceptable... for example, I could perhaps default to "unspecified" so that only explicitly local or UTC dates have a value.

Comment: Marc, why is DateTime treated different to a custom class created by a user (which has zero 'compatibility') - I would have expected the #1 priority ahead of size/speed was having the object recreated in its original state.

Comment: @wal perhaps it simply hasn't been an issue most times. I'm not against adding the "kind" to the v2 data if we need - just mentioning the impact, that's all.

Comment: It is common to store Dates in UTC. When they are sent over the wire protobuf loses this information (`Kind`)which means displaying it on the client side in their timezone will not work. I'm surprised no one has run into this earlier?

Comment: @MarcGravell, has anything changed in the current version? I am currently running into the exact same issue, I serialize utc and get back unspecified. Is there any simple workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to change kind property for DTO and always set it to UTC. This may not be acceptable for all the application, but works for me

```
class DateTimeWrapper 
{
    private DateTime _date;

    public DateTime Date 
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set { _date = new DateTime(value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);}
    }
}
```

#### Update

After using protobuf for more than a year and integrating C#, Java, Python and Scala I came to conclusion that one should use a long representation for the DateTime. For example using UNIX time. It's painful to translate C# DateTime protobuf object to other languages DateTime. However, something as simple as long is understood by all.

Answer (score 2):

It might make more sense for protobuf to automatically deserialize the DateTime with the UtcKind, that way if you are using Utc as your base, which I think is best practice anyway, you wont have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation for a workaround. Let me know if you can find a better solution. Thanks!

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
public class ProtoDateTime
{
    [ProtoIgnore]
    private DateTime? _val;

    [ProtoIgnore]
    private DateTime Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_val != null)
            {
                return _val.Value;
            }
            lock (this)
            {
                if (_val != null)
                {
                    return _val.Value;
                }
                _val = new DateTime(DateTimeWithoutKind.Ticks, Kind);
            }
            return _val.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                _val = value;
                Kind = value.Kind;
                DateTimeWithoutKind = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private DateTimeKind Kind { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    private DateTime DateTimeWithoutKind { get; set; }


    public static DateTime getValue(ref ProtoDateTime wrapper)
    {
        if (wrapper == null)
        {
            wrapper = new ProtoDateTime();
        }
        return wrapper.Value;
    }

    public static DateTime? getValueNullable(ref ProtoDateTime wrapper)
    {
        if (wrapper == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return wrapper.Value;

    }

    public static void setValue(out ProtoDateTime wrapper, DateTime value)
    {
        wrapper = new ProtoDateTime { Value = value };
    }

    public static void setValue(out ProtoDateTime wrapper, DateTime? newVal)
    {
        wrapper = newVal.HasValue ? new ProtoDateTime { Value = newVal.Value } : null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
public class MyClass
{
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    [XmlIgnore]
    private ProtoDateTime _timestampWrapper { get; set; }
    [ProtoIgnore]
    public DateTime Timestamp
    {
        get
        {
            return ProtoDateTime.getValue(ref _timestampWrapper);
        }
        set
        {
            return ProtoDateTime.setValue(out _timestampWrapper, value);
        }
    }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    [XmlIgnore]
    private ProtoDateTime _nullableTimestampWrapper { get; set; }
    [ProtoIgnore]
    public DateTime? NullableTimestamp
    {
        get
        {
            return ProtoDateTime.getValueNullable(ref _nullableTimestampWrapper);
        }
        set
        {
            return ProtoDateTime.setValue(out _nullableTimestampWrapper, value);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only need a single `DateTimeKind` (i.e. `UTC` or `Local`) there's a simple (though not pretty) solution.

Since internally protobuf-net converts `DateTime`'s into Unix-Time representation it has a single `DateTime` value representing the Unix epoch (1970/01/01) to which it adds the relevant delta each time.

If you replace that value using reflection with a `UTC` or `Local` `DateTime` value, all your `DateTime`s will have that specified `DateTimeKind`:

```
typeof (BclHelpers).
    GetField("EpochOrigin", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).
    SetValue(null, new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));
```

You can read more about in on [my blog](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/10/03/protobuf-net-datetime-bug/)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with protobuf-net 2.2 (see [commit](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/commit/e601b359c6ae56afc159754d29f5e7d0f05a01f5)), there is a possibility to opt-in to the serialization of DateTime.Kind. You can set a global flag. The corresponding [issue](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues/44) on github (still open).

And here is a [usage example](https://github.com/Particular/docs.particular.net/blob/master/Snippets/ProtoBufNet/ProtoBufNet_1/Usage.cs) in connection with NServiceBus.

Disclaimer: This won't help for the old protobuf-net version the OP is referring to, but this is an old question, and may be helpful for others.