# How to serialize the DateTime field with DateTimeKind option through ProtoBuf-net

Tags: c#, datetime, protobuf-net

How to serialize the date time field with DateTimeKind option through ProtoBuf. When deserializing i want that date time field with DateTimeKind option.

I know we can achieve this by adding one additional property to convert the deserialized value in the UTC format.

For example, i have one date time field called UtcDateTime. it has the value in the UTC kind format. When serialize and deserialize this value i am getting the proper result, but it failed to retrieve date time kind option.

**Here is my sample code:**

```
[ProtoIgnore]                
public DateTime UtcDateTime { get; set; }

[ProtoMember(3)]           
public DateTime DateTimeValue           
{
    get { return UtcDateTime ; }
    set { UtcDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc); }   
}
```

Now consider my case, my application has many date time fields like this. Instead of adding additional property in all places i need one generic solution to achieve this. If possible, please explain how to achieve this with sample C# logic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include this code to run before serializing or deserializing anything:

```cs
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.IncludeDateTimeKind = true;
```

Now your contract can be as simple as this (no need to double the properties):

```cs
[ProtoMember(3)]           
public DateTime DateTimeValue { get; set; }
```

And the value of `DateTimeKind` will be written and read automatically.

#### Compatibility concern

It worth noting that the original Protocol Buffers specification doesn't include `DateTimeKind` (it's specific to .NET) -- see [protobuf-net does not deserialize DateTime.Kind correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659185/protobuf-net-does-not-deserialize-datetime-kind-correctly) . Opt-in support of serializing `DateTimeKind` was [added](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/commit/e601b359c6ae56afc159754d29f5e7d0f05a01f5) in protobuf-net v2.1.0.

If you exchange these messages with another system, it won't work unless the other end uses protobuf-net and sets `IncludeDateTimeKind` to `true`.

Comment: Clarification: the "protocol buffers" specification doesn't touch this *at all*; protobuf-net added this at some point, but the recommendation would be to use the well-known types (using DataFormat.WellKnown; this uses the newer "Timestamp" layout); the well-known types *also* don't support any concept of "kind"